# How do I complete the "Get hit by a car" challenge in Goat Simulator?

Tags: goat-simulator

I'm playing the newly-updated 1.1 version of Goat Simulator.  One of the new challenges in the game is to "Get hit by a car".  I have mercilessly thrown my goat into every type of car and truck I could find, but to no avail.  What department of goat do I need to register with in order to get rewarded for my reckless behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sadly enough, this appears to be a bug as reported [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/265930/discussions/1/522728814730374041/):

> "Car Accident" quest in the Goat Bay does not work. I get hit by those cars driving down the road, but the resulting 20 points lists no source. Trucks work fine, it reads those, but it doesn't read those cars as capable of inflicting "Hit by a car".

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible in goatville (I’ve done it before), but I’m not sure about Goat Bay. Maybe you have a different version of the game (I have goat simulator: the goaty on Nintendo switch).

Comment: Welcome to gaming.se - this post is very old, and there wasn't a Nintendo Switch when it was originally posted, let alone a Goat Simulator release for the Switch.  There was only the Steam store version. I'd update the question, but it hasn't significantly changed since it was posted, so I'll just suggest you update this answer to reflect that it is specifically providing information relevant to the Switch release.